# dynamic.ooo plugin carousel customizations

Tags: php, css, wordpress

I am using the dynamic.ooo plugin in my WordPress site to show some posts in a carousel dynamically.The posts change time to time.I want to show the first three posts with a border. How can i access the first three posts. I have tried by some php functions but it is not working.

I tried some php codes but they don't work. I can't find the correct classes or dont know how to target only first three posts

Comment: Should be possible using [`:nth-child()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-child) selectors, but on what you actually need to apply them, of course depends on what HTML structure this plugin creates for the carousel.